# Using an array list with a hash table

Tags: algorithm

I'm attempting to build a simple hash table from scratch. The hash table I have currently uses an array of linked lists. The hashing function takes the hash value of a key-pair objects modulo the size of the array for indexing. This is all well and good, but I'm wondering if I could dynamically expand my array by using an array-list once it starts to fill up (Tell me why this is not a good idea if you think so). Obviously the hash function would be compromised since we're finding indexes using the array length. What would be a good hash function to use that would allow my array of linked-lists to expand while not compromising the integrity of the hash function?

Comment: typically you double the size of the underlying array once you reach a certain fill factor and re-hash all elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you will have to re-hash all elements after expanding the bucket array. It can be done by iterating over the contents of the old hash table, and inserting them into the newly expanded hash table.

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I was looking for.